# ANT: parsing list of properties for exec args

Tags: ant

I'm using ant to manage a bunch of binary compiles for people who may have less technical knowledge in compiling/installing Linux binaries. Operations level stuff like Apache httpd and OpenSSL.

In an effort to keep things clean, understandable and maintainable I'm trying to parameterize everything I can at the top of the build.xml, then have a line of "<!-- DO NOT MODIFY ANYTHING BELOW HERE -->" where all the real build logic takes place.

The one sticking point I've got is how to handle the ./configure parameters. One of my goals is that someone in ops can just copy the build file, change a few parameters at the top and build a new version without any hand-holding.

I see the Exec Task has a "command" attribute that technically fulfills this, but it's deprecated and I don't want to depend on it continuing to exist going forward. If I were doing something like this in Bash, I'd just iterate over an array but I see no way to do this in ant.

Is there a way to parameterize exec arguments of unknown length? If not, is there an alternative build manager that would be better for what I'm doing?

Comment: Why don't you just create a build properties file, imported into the build as follows:   <property file="build.properties"/>

Comment: I could do that, but how does the configure target know how many to use?

Comment: Don't understand the question. What configure target? Perhaps some source code would help clarify the question

Comment: Here's the build.xml I'm working on:
http://pastebin.com/nWJ8MVZQ

Comment: I meant posting here, where a record would be kept of the question details.

Comment: I quickly reviewed that link and don't understand why you're calling one build tool "make" from another "ant".

Comment: I would have to write another build script regardless, as this is a general framework I'm using to compile a number of binary packages (nginx, openssl, httpd, etc). I picked ant because it's one of the easier ones to understand, and the people I'm handing it off to are not the most technical people on the planet.

The goal of this exercise is to make it dead simple for someone to compile a new version of these programs without someone holding their hand through the process.